# Component in a JScrollPane stops receiving KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing

I am putting a component ( derivative on JPanel ) inside a JScrollPane.

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(component);
```

since the component occasionally changes size, I have to occasionally do :

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

          public void run()
          {
            scrollPane.getViewport().setView(component);
            component.repaint();
          }
    });
```

Also, the component can receive KeyEvents

```
    component.addKeyListener(this);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            component.setFocusable(true);
            component.requestFocusInWindow();       
        }
    });
```

However, the component never receives any Key Events. Even the code in `keyTyped()` does not execute ( I put a `System.out.println()` there).
What is more baffling, is, in debug mode, I can pause the main thread, when the AWT event thread would accept key events. But during normal execution, it does not work.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you must set the view again? Doesn't the component handle the size changes correctly? Have you considered implementing java.swing.Scrollable?

Comment: Kindly tell me how can the component handle size changes correctly ? Like ... what are the steps ?

Comment: Replacing scrollPane.getViewport().setView(component); with component.revalidate(), along with Scrollable, solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my component java.swing.Scrollable, and replacing `scrollPane.getViewport().setView(component);`
with `component.revalidate` solved my prioblem.

Thanks ordnungswidrig!